# Can anyone suggest me a single unix command through which I can get only the last 15 minute logs from any log file

Tags: putty

I am looking for a single unix command not a lines of codes or something like. 
I have already tried with sed and awk command but not working for me.
sed command works but sometimes it returns nothing and awk is giving me the result but not specific for last 15minute

Comment: Consider attaching or adding a part of your log file with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly what we do is to read last 100 or 500 lines from log file like this

```
tail -n500 /var/log/messages
```

last 500 lines will be enough for 15 mints logs

Comment: Hello Mohtisham, Thank you for your answer but with this solution I cannot be sure with the output. It should give me all last 15min logs